# docker-compose.yml with 3 zookepers and 1 broker set up with public IP - broker failed to start with no meaningful logs (but works with 1 zookeeper)

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper-1
    container_name: zookeeper-1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 2888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 3888
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "localhost:2888:3888;192.168.100.14:12888:13888;192.168.100.14:22888:23888"
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-1:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-logs-1:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    networks:
      - mynet

  zookeeper-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper-2
    container_name: zookeeper-2
    ports:
      - "12181:12181"
      - "12888:12888"
      - "13888:13888"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 12181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 12888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 13888
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "192.168.100.14:2888:3888;localhost:12888:13888;192.168.100.14:22888:23888"
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-2:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-logs-2:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    networks:
      - mynet

  zookeeper-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper-3
    container_name: zookeeper-3
    ports:
      - "22181:22181"
      - "22888:22888"
      - "23888:23888"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 22888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 23888
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "192.168.100.14:2888:3888;192.168.100.14:12888:13888;localhost:22888:23888"
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-3:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-logs-3:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    networks:
      - mynet

  broker-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1
    hostname: broker-1
    container_name: broker-1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://192.168.100.14:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: OUTSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "192.168.100.14:2181,192.168.100.14:12181,192.168.100.14:22181"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE: 'LogAppendTime'
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS: 31536000000 # 1 year
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/kafka-1:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - mynet

  # PORT 8081 reserved for Schema Registry

  kafka-rest-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.2.1
    hostname: kafka-rest-1
    container_name: kafka-rest-1
    depends_on:
      - broker-1
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: 192.168.100.14
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8082
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 192.168.100.14:9092
    networks:
      - mynet

  # PORT 8083 reserved for Kafka-Connect REST API

  kafka-ui-1:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:0.2.1
    hostname: kafka-ui-1
    container_name: kafka-ui-1
    depends_on:
      - broker-1
    ports:
      - "8084:8080"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: lab
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: 192.168.100.14:9092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: "192.168.100.14:2181;192.168.100.14:12181;192.168.100.14:22181"
    networks:
      - mynet

  kafdrop-1:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:3.27.0
    hostname: kafrop-1
    container_name: kafdrop-1
    depends_on:
      - broker-1
    ports:
      - "8085:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: 192.168.100.14:9092
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms32M -Xmx64M"
      SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXTPATH: "/"
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

Also found here at stackoverflow that zookeper ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS should not have external IP of itself (should be 'localhost' there), so my 3 zookeepers are started to work together.

But my broker-1 fails to start and exits with 'Exit 1' code and log is always:

```
# docker-compose up broker-1
zookeeper-1 is up-to-date
Starting broker-1 ... done
Attaching to broker-1
broker-1        | ===> User
broker-1        | uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
broker-1        | ===> Configuring ...
broker-1        | ===> Running preflight checks ...
broker-1        | ===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
broker-1        | ===> Check if Zookeeper is healthy ...
broker-1        | SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
broker-1        | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
broker-1        | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-simple-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
broker-1        | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
broker-1        | SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
broker-1        | log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.ZookeeperReadyCommand).
broker-1        | log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
broker-1        | log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

broker-1 exited with code 1
```

But if I comment out additional zookeepers, then broker-1 started well, this is config that works:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper-1
    container_name: zookeeper-1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 2888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 3888
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "localhost:2888:3888" #;192.168.100.14:12888:13888;192.168.100.14:22888:23888"
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-1:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-logs-1:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    networks:
      - mynet

#  zookeeper-2:
#    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
#    hostname: zookeeper-2
#    container_name: zookeeper-2
#    ports:
#      - "12181:12181"
#      - "12888:12888"
#      - "13888:13888"
#    environment:
#      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
#      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 12181
#      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 12888
#      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 13888
#      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
#      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
#      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
#      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "192.168.100.14:2888:3888;localhost:12888:13888;192.168.100.14:22888:23888"
#    volumes:
#      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-2:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
#      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-logs-2:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
#    networks:
#      - mynet
#
#  zookeeper-3:
#    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
#    hostname: zookeeper-3
#    container_name: zookeeper-3
#    ports:
#      - "22181:22181"
#      - "22888:22888"
#      - "23888:23888"
#    environment:
#      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
#      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
#      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 22888
#      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 23888
#      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
#      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
#      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
#      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "192.168.100.14:2888:3888;192.168.100.14:12888:13888;localhost:22888:23888"
#    volumes:
#      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-3:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
#      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-logs-3:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
#    networks:
#      - mynet

  broker-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1
    hostname: broker-1
    container_name: broker-1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
#      - zookeeper-2
#      - zookeeper-3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://192.168.100.14:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: OUTSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "192.168.100.14:2181" #,192.168.100.14:12181,192.168.100.14:22181"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE: 'LogAppendTime'
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS: 31536000000 # 1 year
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/kafka-1:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - mynet

  # PORT 8081 reserved for Schema Registry

  kafka-rest-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.2.1
    hostname: kafka-rest-1
    container_name: kafka-rest-1
    depends_on:
      - broker-1
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: 192.168.100.14
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8082
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 192.168.100.14:9092
    networks:
      - mynet

  # PORT 8083 reserved for Kafka-Connect REST API

  kafka-ui-1:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:0.2.1
    hostname: kafka-ui-1
    container_name: kafka-ui-1
    depends_on:
      - broker-1
    ports:
      - "8084:8080"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: lab
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: 192.168.100.14:9092
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: "192.168.100.14:2181" #;192.168.100.14:12181;192.168.100.14:22181"
    networks:
      - mynet

  kafdrop-1:
    image: obsidiandynamics/kafdrop:3.27.0
    hostname: kafrop-1
    container_name: kafdrop-1
    depends_on:
      - broker-1
    ports:
      - "8085:9000"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: 192.168.100.14:9092
      JVM_OPTS: "-Xms32M -Xmx64M"
      SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXTPATH: "/"
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

What's wrong with 3-zookeepers config and why 1-zookeerper config is ok for single kafka broker?

**UPD:** Of cource I know that 3 zookeepers and 3 brokers (one now) makes no sense on the same host :-)
I need to simulate several hosts environment on the single host that I have, by using docker containers.
Plan is to switch off some of docker containers then to simulate different "hosts" (zookeper, broker) failures.
That's why I'm using "public" IP address 192.168.100.14 ("public" from container point of view) and different ports in configs for such simulation.
Docker *bridged* networking used, i.e. it's np to access to network hosts and even to Internet hosts by IP from inside of container - I tested that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem totally resolved for me! :-)**

It seems Docker container bridged network adds problems to interconnect all stuff in the cluster.

Adding **ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_LISTEN_ON_ALL_IPS: 'true'** to zookeper env and **extra_hosts:** to all containers solved all my problems! :-)

So I added into each config of each service the following lines with **extra_hosts** :

```
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka-1:192.168.1.11"
      - "kafka-2:192.168.1.12"
      - "kafka-3:192.168.1.13"
```

Also it's important to add **ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_LISTEN_ON_ALL_IPS: 'true'** to zookeper environment.

Full example:

```
version: '3.7'

x-zoo: &zoo "kafka-1:2888:3888;kafka-2:2888:3888;kafka-3:2888:3888"
x-kafkaZookeepers: &kafkaZookeepers "kafka-1:2181,kafka-2:2181,kafka-3:2181"
x-kafkaBrokers: &kafkaBrokers "kafka-1:9092"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka-1:192.168.1.11"
      - "kafka-2:192.168.1.12"
      - "kafka-3:192.168.1.13"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_LISTEN_ON_ALL_IPS: 'true'
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 2888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 3888
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: *zoo
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-logs:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    networks:
      - mynet

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka-1:192.168.1.11"
      - "kafka-2:192.168.1.12"
      - "kafka-3:192.168.1.13"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: OUTSIDE://192.168.1.11:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: OUTSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: *kafkaZookeepers
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_TIMESTAMP_TYPE: 'LogAppendTime'
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS: 31536000000 # 1 year
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/kafka:/var/lib/kafka/data
    networks:
      - mynet

  kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui:0.2.1
    hostname: kafka-ui
    container_name: kafka-ui
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8084:8080"
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka-1:192.168.1.11"
      - "kafka-2:192.168.1.12"
      - "kafka-3:192.168.1.13"
    environment:
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: local_kafka
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: *kafkaBrokers
      KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER: *kafkaZookeepers
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

**docker-compose.yml** files on other VMs looks similar (I set up only 3 zookeepers for now), on 2nd VM:

```
version: '3.7'

x-zoo: &zoo "kafka-1:2888:3888;kafka-2:2888:3888;kafka-3:2888:3888"
x-kafkaZookeepers: &kafkaZookeepers "kafka-1:2181,kafka-2:2181,kafka-3:2181"
x-kafkaBrokers: &kafkaBrokers "kafka-1:9092"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka-1:192.168.1.11"
      - "kafka-2:192.168.1.12"
      - "kafka-3:192.168.1.13"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_LISTEN_ON_ALL_IPS: 'true'
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 2888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 3888
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: *zoo
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-logs:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

and on 3rd VM:

```
version: '3.7'

x-zoo: &zoo "kafka-1:2888:3888;kafka-2:2888:3888;kafka-3:2888:3888"
x-kafkaZookeepers: &kafkaZookeepers "kafka-1:2181,kafka-2:2181,kafka-3:2181"
x-kafkaBrokers: &kafkaBrokers "kafka-1:9092"

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    extra_hosts:
      - "kafka-1:192.168.1.11"
      - "kafka-2:192.168.1.12"
      - "kafka-3:192.168.1.13"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_LISTEN_ON_ALL_IPS: 'true'
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 2888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 3888
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: *zoo
    volumes:
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - ./kafka-data/zookeeper-logs:/var/lib/zookeeper/log
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

And according the logs all Docker containers now may connect each other ok.

I also added my hosts kafka-1, kafka-2, kafka-3 to /etc/hosts file on VMs:

```
test@kafka-1:~/Kafka-Docker$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       kafka-1

192.168.1.11    kafka-1
192.168.1.12    kafka-2
192.168.1.13    kafka-3

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Hope it will save somebody's time and nerves and perhas that was the answer I was waiting for! :-)

Also note that I'm using latest atm (see date) docker images (cp-zookeper,cp-kafka,etc.) **6.2.1** from dockerhub from official confluent publisher.

**UPD:** I forward port 4888->8080 on each zookeeper and got **simple REST admin page** ( https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.9/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkCommands ) where I may see who is "leader" and who is "follower" , examples:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pzJd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3M7T.png)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand Docker Compose networking. You should always be using service names, not IP addresses

---

If you use one Zookeeper server, `ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS` doesn't do anything. This is used to join a cluster

So, you're looking for this

```
services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper-1
    container_name: zookeeper-1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 2888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 3888
      ...
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "localhost:2888:3888;zookeeper-1:12888:13888;zookeeper-2:22888:23888"
    ...

  zookeeper-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper-2
    container_name: zookeeper-2
    ports:
      - "12181:12181"
      - "12888:12888"
      - "13888:13888"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 12181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 12888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 13888
      ...
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "zookeeper-1:2888:3888;localhost:12888:13888;zookeeper-2:22888:23888"
    ...

  zookeeper-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper-3
    container_name: zookeeper-3
    ports:
      - "22181:22181"
      - "22888:22888"
      - "23888:23888"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
      ZOOKEEPER_PEER_PORT: 22888
      ZOOKEEPER_LEADER_PORT: 23888
      ...
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "zookeeper-1:2888:3888;zookeeper-2:12888:13888;localhost:22888:23888"
    ...

  broker-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1
    hostname: broker-1
    container_name: broker-1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    # ports removed because the listener is internal to the docker network only
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://broker-1:9092
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper-1:zookeeper-2:12181,zookeeper-3:22181"
      ...
```

... And so on ...

Also use `broker-1:9092` for the bootstrap servers for the other containers

Keep in mind that you're using a single host, which is a single point of failure, and therefore more than one ZK server is pointless

Comment: thanks! will hostnames zookeeper-1, zookeeper-2, and so on work across different servers with different IP addesses?
also I noticed that KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT works well if I put one IP address there but doesn't work if I put 3 addresses - how it may be explained then?

Comment: > Keep in mind that you're using a single host, which is a single point of failure, and therefore more than one ZK server is pointless
 
| yes, exactly! but my task is to use single host to simulate different hosts (will switch containers off one by one to simulate hosts down), that's why I use not docker hostnames, but public IP addresses and ports. in the docker I use bridged networking as you may see in config.

Comment: How I understand Docker _bridged_ networking: containers are connected (internally) together like they're different hosts connected to a hub/switch HW, also main "outside" host connected to the bridge too so conrtainers may access it. Also tested that netcat or telnet may easily connect to another hosts in real physical network and even to Internet services from inside Docker container, so I see no problem in using public IPs in config. (ofc I understand that internal Docker containers hostanmes preferrable in most cases of inter-container communications, but not in my particular case)

Comment: If you really want to simulate multiple host networking properly, then use VMs, not Docker. And I've never used IP's to connect services, so cannot help you there. If you really want to create a Kafka cluster with multiple components, then https://stimzi.io is where I would go

Comment: perhaps yes. thanks! I was able to run 3 zookeepers and 1 broker and connect them all together if I use Docker-local hostnames set inside config, i.e. zookeeper-1,zookeeper-2,etc. Will try to set up several VMs then (in VirtualBox Windows, and guest Ubuntu 16.04) and test. Is that ok to set up 3 VMs with zookeeper+broker on each or better to have 6 VMs for that?

Comment: To limit resource usage, running ZK on the same machine as Kafka can work, but generally doesn't match production environment

Comment: I think that I just need to find working config example for 3 hosts (VMs in my case) where zookeeper+broker running inside Docker containers on each.

Comment: No, you wouldn't use Docker inside of the VMs. That would just complicate things unless you actually move to using Docker Swarm or Kubernetes

Comment: It was successfully used by my predecessor - he ran zookeeper+broker on each VM inside Docker containers. But configs lost :-( I need to do the same, I know it's possible. Running 3 zookeepers and 3 brokers on the same VM makes no sense. We have 3 physical powerful servers, a lots of VMs inside each, and for simple deploy we have Docker containers inside VMs.

Comment: It's not really possible to lose configs; those are in the environment variables. The data directories need to be mounted on the host, though, yes. Kubernetes persistent volumes manage this fine. You can setup a k8s cluster in VMs, then let the orchestrator manage the containers (and network and storage), because that's what it is meant to do. Don't re-invent the wheel

Comment: It seems adding extra_hosts into each Docker solved my problem.

Comment: Adding ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM_LISTEN_ON_ALL_IPS: 'true' and "extra_hosts:" in each container solved all connectivity problems! :-)